# Retaking Shahada

Tags: shahada, sects

Asalamulakum everyone,

I would really appreciate any advice I can get. For sake of privacy I will keep details to a minimum.
I was born into Islam but into a sect (if you will) that is not greatly liked. I have had my doubts about it the last few years but only started to research and act on these doubts for a year now. I am leaning more towards what I believe may be the true Islam, however my question is, do I have to retake my shahada or is it the belief in my heart that makes me a Muslim?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As-salamu Alaykum

If you were a born Muslim and firmly believed that Allah is the only God and that Muhammad is his messenger, as well as in the six pillars of iman—for if one does not hold to even one of the six pillars of iman, he is not a Muslim—you do not need to make the shahada. Here are the six pillars of Islam:

1. Iman in Allah is the Main one in Pillars of Iman
2. Iman In The Angels
3. Iman In The Books
4. Iman In The Messengers
5. Iman In The Day of Judgement
6. Iman In Qadar(destiny)

Don't worry; if you have always upheld the six pillars of iman, you are a Muslim. I would be more helpful if you gave a deeper explanation about the sect :).